# Typings can't find provider within Ionic 2 App

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb, typescript-typings

I have create a service that initializes a PouchDB database, and am trying to call the service and it's method within another one of my components. I keep getting this error:

```
    [23:43:34]  Error: Error at /Users/Brad/IonicApps/CMTAv2/.tmp/pages/projects/projects.ts:24:27 
[23:43:34]  Cannot find name 'ProjectService'. 
[23:43:34]  ngc failed 
[23:43:34]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[23:43:34]  Error: Error
```

Here is my code for the service:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

/*
  Generated class for the ProjectService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/

let PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  private _db;
  private _projects;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello ProjectService Provider');
  }

  initDB() {
    this._db = new PouchDB('Projects', { adapter: 'websql' });
  }

  add(project) {
    return this._db.post(project);
  }

  delete(project) {
    return this._db.remove(project);
  }

  getAll() {

    if (!this._projects) {
      return this._db.allDocs({ include_docs: true})
          .then(docs => {

            // Each row has a .doc object and we just want to send an
            // array of birthday objects back to the calling controller,
            // so let's map the array to contain just the .doc objects.

            this._projects = docs.rows.map(row => {
              // Dates are not automatically converted from a string.
              row.doc.Date = new Date(row.doc.Date);
              return row.doc;
            });

            // Listen for changes on the database.
            this._db.changes({ live: true, since: 'now', include_docs: true})
                .on('change', this.onDatabaseChange);

            return this._projects;
          });
    } else {
      // Return cached data as a promise
      return this._projects;
    }
  }

  private onDatabaseChange = (change) => {
    var index = this.findIndex(this._projects, change.id);
    var project = this._projects[index];

    if (change.deleted) {
      if (project) {
        this._projects.splice(index, 1); // delete
      }
    } else {
      change.doc.Date = new Date(change.doc.Date);
      if (project && project._id === change.id) {
        this._projects[index] = change.doc; // update
      } else {
        this._projects.splice(index, 0, change.doc) // insert
      }
    }
  }

  // Binary search, the array is by default sorted by _id.
  private findIndex(array, id) {
    var low = 0, high = array.length, mid;
    while (low < high) {
      mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
      array[mid]._id < id ? low = mid + 1 : high = mid
    }
    return low;
  }


}
```

Here is my code for the other component:

```
    import {Component, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { ReportsPage } from '../reports/reports';
import { ProjectDetailPage } from '../project-detail/project-detail';
import { ProjectService } from  '../../providers/project-service.ts';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  Generated class for the Projects page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/



@Component({
  selector: 'page-projects',
  templateUrl: 'projects.html',
  providers: [ProjectService]
})
export class ProjectsPage {
  public projects = [];
  private projectService: ProjectService;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private platform: Platform,
              private zone: NgZone) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.projectService.initDB();
      this.projectService.getAll()
          .then(data => {
            this.zone.run(() => {
              this.projects = data;
            });
          })
          .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello Projects Page');

  }

  public addProject() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ProjectDetailPage);
    modal.present();
  }

  public openProject(project) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ReportsPage);
  }

}
```

Any reason why this might be happening? I have tried messing with the declarations in app.module.ts, but that did not do anything. My IDE is telling me that it can locate 'ProjectService', so there is not an issue there. Do I have to declare the provider within a Typings config or something?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: providers are module level , then put a private member of type projectService in the contractor.

Comment: have the same problem, but I only load the provider in the app.module file! Import is working as well, but when I will call the service in the constructor I get the error can't find service.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are not instantiating the service.

```
export class ProjectsPage {
  public projects = [];
  private projectService: ProjectService;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private platform: Platform,
              private zone: NgZone) {
```

There you are just saying there is an object projectService with a type ProjectService, but you are not creating it. You can either move it to the constructor arguments:

```
export class ProjectsPage {
  public projects = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private projectService: ProjectService;
              private platform: Platform,
              private zone: NgZone) {
```

or inside the constructor:

```
this.projectService = new ProjectService(this.http); <-- Need to add http to your constructor arguments.
```

The first option is the best one, the second one should only be used if you are waiting for a condition to happen before instantiating the service.

Comment: Also remove the .ts from the import. You don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-projects',
  templateUrl: 'projects.html',
  providers: [ProjectService]
})
```

> Don't use providers inside components. Remove Provider from component and add only in app.module.ts

Comment: I see how that can provide for redundancy. Did not fix the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

> My IDE is telling me that it can locate 'ProjectService', so there is
>   not an issue there. Do I have to declare the provider within a Typings
>   config or something?

Assuming that the path used in the import is correct, try by removing the `.ts` from the import sentence:

```
import { ProjectService } from  '../../providers/project-service.ts';
```

should be just

```
import { ProjectService } from  '../../providers/project-service';
```

And also just like @Aravind said, don't use the `providers` inside components; use the one in `NgModule` instead:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,

    // Pages
    Page1,
    Page2,

    // Pipes
    MyCustomPipe,

    // Directives
    MyCustomDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,

    // Pages
    Page1,
    Page2
  ],
  providers: [ ProjectService, ... ] // <- here!
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got my problem. The path for the imported file was wrong! So check if your pathes are right.

Comment: please let me know, what exactly was wrong in the path?